# How can I cut off by points of intersection in Sketch?

Tags: path, sketch-app

Say, I have two triangles like at this picture:

[image]

---

Using Sketch. I want to cut off the upper part of the red triangle, the one above the black triangle. I can manually create a couple of sub-paths in the red triangle, cut them off and then close path again. But I definitely want to learn the better way, since it's not always about such simple shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@shabunc.

I'd do this:
1. duplicate the upper shape and hide it;

2. select the original shapes and use "Subtract" to subtract the top shape from the bottom one.
3. Hit "Flatten", so the new shape breaks up into several smaller shapes in a group.
4. select the unnecessary shapes in the new flattened group and hit delete
5. enable the duplicated shape from step 1.

Voila!

Check out the short video I made with the process:
[image: Process GIF]